# Comparing two files in a script

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
while read file1 <&3; do
     while read file2 ; do       
        if [ $file1 == $file2 ] ; then
         $file1 >> /infanass/dev/admin/test/newlist.txt
        fi
    echo "$file1"
    echo "$file2"
 done 3</infanass/dev/admin/test/file2.txt
done 3</infanass/dev/admin/test/file1.txt
```

I want to read one line from file1.txt and then loop through file2.txt and see if there is a match and if there is write it out too a new text file..

I think I have a infinite loop..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a simpler approach?

```
while read line do
    grep "^$line$" file2.txt >>matches.txt
done < file1.txt
```

**Explanation:**

This loops through `file1.txt` line by line and uses `grep` to look for the exact line in `file2.txt`. Now `grep` will output the line again if it was able to match it in `file2.txt` and it's then redirected (appended) to the file `matches.txt`.

The reason your script is stalling is that your second loop is awaiting input on `stdin`: you forgot to make its `stdin` a duplicate of file descriptor `3` as you did with the first one. In any case, no extra file descriptors need be created: you can just redirect `stdin` so that the `while` loop reads from a file and not the terminal.

Comment: Also, you don't want both read commands to be trying to read from the same file descriptor.

Comment: that works thanks! Is there a way to add .pdf to the end of the match when i write it to >>mathes.txt ? Assuming i already parsed off the extensions and its just the basename

Comment: @mkrouse You're most welcome. For future reference, we generally use upvotes and accepts (which you've already done) as a thank you without needing to post anything. This might sound strange/insensitive but it helps keep comments and discussion to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`comm`](http://man.cx/comm) to find the intersection:

```
comm -12 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) > newlist.txt
```

comm requires its input files to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it even simpler by feeding *file1* as search terms to grep and let it search for it in *file2*?

```
$ grep -f file1 file2 > file3
```

Please note that on some platforms you need/want egrep or ggrep because of performance issues.